# Unable to apply back button in inner page in Ionic app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
$scope.myGoBack = function() {
    $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
       disableBack: true
    });

    $state.go('home');
};


<ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear" ng-click="myGoBack()">
     <span class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-left"><i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> </span>
</ion-nav-back-button>
```

When I am trying to apply back button in inner pages then its not working.  Click function is not working. Please help me what am I doing wrong. I  have tried much but still it's not working. Please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-click="$ionicGoBack()"` instead.

Comment: no its not working where we have to apply this what about ionicGoBack method please suggest me

Comment: Replace your current ng-click on the element with the above.

Comment: I did same thing but still its not working can i give u demo code

Comment: can u please help me coz i  stucking in this issue

Comment: sorry I slept last night, you can give me your code and point out what the problem is, i.e. what you want to be done.

Comment: OK are u there can i send You my code https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B6-Tx6qkeFMgLTBIU3lXcU9nQnM&usp=sharing_eid&ts=56d6eb93

Comment: in the given Code my back Button is not working Properly please help me where am doing wrong